# Initialization of vector of vector is very slow

Tags: c++, performance, vector, initialization

I have a vector of vectors and I am trying to initialize it as follows:

```
vector<vector<float> > matrix(numberOfRows, vector<float> (numberOfCols));
```

But this line lasts about 0.89 where the numberOfRows and numberOfCols are:

```
const uint32_t numRows = 10000;
const uint32_t numCols = 20000;
```

Whereas initializing dynamics array with the following code take 0.04 sec to execute:

```
float **matrix = new float*[numberOfRows];
for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfRows; ++i)
    matrix[i] = new float[numberOfCols];
```

Am I doing something wrong is there any faster way to initialize that vector?

**Edit:**

As for the questions:

I used g++-4.5 to test using O3 optimization level with default standard.

Comment: What compiler, and are you compiling with optimizations on?

Comment: What version of the C++ standard are you using?

Comment: You might see some improvement by allocating one big chunk instead of 10000 smaller ones. Be aware that in 32-bit Windows you won't have room for more than two of these (or three with special configuration). It

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference is that the vector is initialized to zero, while the dynamic array is not. With 200 million values, this is noticable.

You have the option of delaying initialization of the vector rows until you have real values to assign them, by not expanding the columns in the initialization.

Comment: I'm afraid that delaying initialization may create bottleneck at the assignment.

Comment: @systemsfault - You can reserve space for each row by calling `reserve(numberOfCols)` for each row if you need to. If you assign each row from some other container, it will fix that itself. It depends on how you are using your matrix.

Comment: Thanks Bo you are right that dropped initialization down to 0.05 secs.

Comment: It would be nice if there were a constructor for vectors that would take the capacity as an argument without actually creating any elements. That way one could construct such a vector of vectors where the outer vector consists of empty vectors, each of which already has the necessary capacity.